# Allow user to insert php variable or equivalent into text field and pull that value from the database

Tags: php

I am trying to work out how to do the following.

At the moment I have a database, one of the tables contains counties in England.

The user is able to add a description for each county and upon performing a search the information for the chosen county is displayed on screen.

Now they have decided that the information will be totally generic to enable them to not have to do a huge amount of updates.

I want to know how I can allow someone to make use of a php variable so that they could efectively drop it into to their text, something like:

```
'Welcome to <?php echo county; ?>.  We offer services in and around <?php echo county; ?>...'
```

I know this could be dangerous but this area is on lockdown and is only available to the admin.

Is there a way to let them do this safely such as give them some sort of shortcode which will be replaced by the county name depending on which county has been searched for?

E.g. if I search for Berkshire the text would read:

'Welcome to Berkshire.  We offer services in and around Berkshire...'

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use bbcode and `str_replace` or `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 2):

Inform user that `[county]` tag is available. Then do simple

```
$content = str_replace('[county]', $county, $content);
```

In that way you don't give access to variable but you inform that if someone puts `[county]` in text it will be transformed with content of `$county` variable.

You can extend this example with more tags and create your own **bbcode** parser.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).. This is way more safer than the echo method.

```
echo sprintf("Welcome to %1$s. We offer services in and around %1$s...", $city);
```

assuming the `$city` is the city variable.